# Text Highlighting. Replace text at position start and end

Tags: javascript

Are there any string replace methods that will replace anything between 2 positions, i.e. range.

When a user highlights a string of text in a textarea I'm able to get the start and end position. I now want to replace that text that's highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use substrings:

```
var newString = 
    originalString.substring(0, startIndex) +
    myReplacementString +
    originalString.substring(endIndex);
```

You could also use regex:

```
var rx = new RegExp('^([\\s\\S]{' + startIndex + '})[\\s\\S]{' + (endIndex - startIndex) + '}([\\s\\S]*)$');
var newString = originalString.replace(rx, '$1' + myReplacementString + '$2');
```

... but I would prefer substrings, in this scenario.